# Record level security in MS Dynamics

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

We want to implement 'Record level security' in MS CRM Dynamics. On **User** and **Case** Entity we have an **OptionSet** which has below values, that Optionset has a lot of values, below are just simple values:

> - Category 1
> - Category 2

We want to restrict **Category 1 users** to see only **Category 1 Cases** and to restrict Category 2 users to see only Category 2 Cases.

What I have done so far?

I was thinking that this should be possible through **Retrieve** plugin, but after I wrote my code.. I found that the retrieve plugin is triggering 5 times when I tried to open a case record. It also does not throw my custom error.

```
    public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        ITracingService tracer = (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));
        IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
        IOrganizationServiceFactory factory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
        IOrganizationService service = factory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

        tracer.Trace("context.Depth = " + context.Depth);

        if (context.Depth > 1)
            return;

        tracer.Trace("context.Stage = " + context.Stage);

        tracer.Trace("context.MessageName = " + context.MessageName);


        EntityReference entityReference = (EntityReference)context.InputParameters["Target"];

        tracer.Trace("entityReferencee = " + entityReference.LogicalName);

        if (context.OutputParameters != null && context.OutputParameters.Contains("BusinessEntity"))
        {
            if (context.OutputParameters["BusinessEntity"] is Entity)
            {
                Entity entity = (Entity)context.OutputParameters["BusinessEntity"];

                tracer.Trace("entity.LogicalName = " + entity.LogicalName);

                context.OutputParameters["BusinessEntity"] = null;

                throw new Exception("You can not view this record.");

            }
            else
            {
                tracer.Trace("BusinessEntity entity is not an entity.");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            tracer.Trace("BusinessEntity entity is null");
        }
    }
```

This is how the plugin is registered:
[image]

Error:
[image]

Detail of Log File is given below:

> Unhandled Exception:
>   System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault,
>   Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException:
>   Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error.  Reference number for
>   administrators or support: #CF526D62Detail:  
>   -2147220970      System.Web.HttpUnhandledException: Microsoft Dynamics
>   CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or
>   support: #CF526D62
>   2015-09-21T12:33:00.6154994Z   
>       -2147220956
>       
>       Unexpected exception from plug-in (Execute): RestrictUserAccess.Case: System.Exception: You can not view this
>   record.
>       2015-09-21T12:33:00.6154994Z
>
> [RestrictUserAccess: RestrictUserAccess.Case]
>   [c8860cb6-4260-e511-80ea-3863bb3600d8: RestrictUserAccess.Case:
>   Retrieve of incident]
>
> context.Depth = 1 context.Stage = 40 context.MessageName = Retrieve
>   entityReferencee = incident entity.LogicalName = incident

Comment: Code of your Retrieve plugin? How did you register your plugin?

Comment: What does the log file (`Download log file`) say ? Also, on a side note, this is what access teams are (supposedly) meant for, have you considered that approach ?

Comment: For which step(s) did you register your plugin? Can you share the Stack Trace?

Comment: @Alex Hmm. I am thinking about using the Access Teams..

Comment: @HenkvanBoeijen I have registered it for "Retrieve Post Operation", see the image in question.

Comment: You should really think about using Team Ownership (not access teams, just two regular teams) or (if it is really only two categories) you could look at using two business units, Category 1 and Category 2, to get the necessary record level security. A plugin for this is overkill.

Answer (score 1):

Your code *does* throw the exception, but the CRM platform handles it as an unexpected error. (Just read the log details.)

When you need to signal a functional error, you have to throw an `InvalidPluginExecutionException`.

It is possible that the system itself is retrieving the same Case record multiple times. Also scripting on your web form or in the ribbon can be responsible for retrieving the same record, e.g. when it needs to evaluate the record state.

Therefore throwing exceptions on retrieval of Case records may not be a useful solution. An alternative approach could be to clear all (or all sensitive) fields on retrieval by removing them from the `Entity.Attributes` collection.

Comment: I have tried InvalidPluginExecutionException too.. We have decided to use Access Team for this functionality.